# How to Put multiple Arrays into one database table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

0I have three arrays... example:

```
phonenums
[0] 555-5555
[1] 555-4444
[2] 555-3333

types
[0] cell
[1] home
[2] work

notes
[0] a note
[1] the babysitters name
[2] call before 6pm
```

They come from a form with dynamically added inputs, so the number of rows is arbitrary.

I want to put these arrays into a table in MySQL, using PHP

```
Table name: customerphones
id
customer_id
phone
type
notes
```

I can get any single array into the database fine, but, when it comes to putting in all three to coordinate with each other (ex: each row[0] to be in one row of the database table)....I'm stuck! I keep rewriting it in different loops or whatnot, and it comes out wrong every time.

I can post my code if it helps explain my situation further. I am just looking for a "concept" here though, to point me in the right direction.

Should I combine the arrays somehow?, or put them into a loop? I don't know!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Here is my solution I came up with (as requested). I'm sure it is not practical at all...and there is probably a much better way to do it. But it got my desired result.

```
// ~~~ Get variables from the form submitted
                    $phonenums = $_POST["phone"];
                    $types = $_POST["type"];
                    $notes = $_POST["notes"];   

                    // ~~~ Queries for Inserting Customer Phone Numbers
                    $querynum = "INSERT INTO customerphones";
                    $querynum .= "(customer_id, phone)";
                    $querynum .= "VALUES (?, ?)";
                    $stmtnum = mysqli_prepare($db, $querynum);

                    $queryty = "UPDATE customerphones SET ";
                    $queryty .= "type = ? ";
                    $queryty .= "WHERE customer_id = ? AND phone = ?";
                    $stmtty = mysqli_prepare($db, $queryty);

                    $queryno = "UPDATE customerphones SET ";
                    $queryno .= "notes = ? ";
                    $queryno .= "WHERE customer_id = ? AND phone = ?";
                    $stmtno = mysqli_prepare($db, $queryno);

                    // Loops for executing the queries to insert phone numbers
                    // (I scraped this together b/c I couldn't get other methods to work...Change this later)
                    $n = 0;
                    foreach($phonenums as $rowph) {                 
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtnum, 'is', $custid, $rowph);
                        mysqli_execute($stmtnum);                       
                        $rct = 0;
                        foreach($types as $rowty) {
                            if($rct == 0) {
                                $x = $types[$n];
                                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtty, 'sis', $x, $custid, $rowph);
                                mysqli_execute($stmtty);
                                $rct++;
                            }
                        } // End Update Phone Type
                        $rct = 0;
                        foreach($notes as $rowno) {
                            if($rct == 0) {
                                $x = $notes[$n];
                                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtno, 'sis', $x, $custid, $rowph);
                                mysqli_execute($stmtno);
                                $rct++;
                            }
                        } // End Update Phone Notes
                        $n++;
                    } // End foreach loops
```

Comment: Proper [database normalization principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) apply here. Create a table for the various bits of data if they're distinct, or one "fact" type table if they're pretty generic.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait... I just saw you update the question with exactly what I listed... Why don't you simply insert each row separately?

Comment: Fill the question a little more: How are you making the connection to MySQL? Is there any more data to insert? And, most importantly, [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @tadman My database is already "normalized". But thanks for the info.

Comment: @Shomz.. I never updated/edited my question..?

Comment: @g.carvalho97 I've tried putting each array into foreach loops, works to get the first array in fine, and then the other two arrays will cancel over itself, so the last row will be repeated. Then tried putting the loops within each other...also wont work. I think Pantamtuy may have answered my question though. But thanks :)

Comment: Oh, wow! I think I just realized a major mistake....I am using some wrong variable names for something...let me fix! :O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm gonna take a shot in the dark here.

Using `PDO` with PreparedStatements, `MultipleIterator` and `ArrayIterator`:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOUR_DATABASE;", "root", "");
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO customerphones(phone, type, notes) VALUES(:phone, :type, :note)");
$m = new MultipleIterator();
$m->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($phonenums), 'phones');
$m->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($types), 'types');
$m->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($notes), 'notes');
foreach($m as $row){
    $sth->bindParam(":phone", $row[0]);
    $sth->bindParam(":type", $row[1]);
    $sth->bindParam(":note", $row[2]);
    $sth->execute();
}
```

I'm assuming that you're using a local MySQL server, and your server's root account isn't password protected.

This works like this:

- Create a new PDO connection with some parameters;
- Prepare a statement with some placeholders for an insert;
- Create an Iterator to unite the arrays;
- Attach all the arrays to the iterator;
- Go through all the iterations of the iterator: Every iteration returns a array with a phone number, a type and a note;
- Bind all the elements of the current iteration to the placeholders of the statement and then execute it.

But please post what you're using to connect to the DB, then I'll refactor my answer.

Comment: I think this may also answer my question (maybe) but I'm going to try Pantamtuy's answer first, because it makes more sense to me (being relatively new to PHP). Thank you

Comment: @omgabee It's just a different approach, but if you're new, just take it easy and go with what you understand. I have to point out though: do not put queries in loops, it clutters your connection and also can leak your data to hackers, so don't do that in production code. But MySQLi has prepared statements too, so you can refactor Pantamtuy's code to use it and make you safer.

Comment: Yes, I actually use prepared statements! I am actually in the process of tailoring it to that. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I would vote up if I had the rep :) :)

Answer (score 0):

using mysqli:

```
$host = 'your_host';
$user = 'your_user';
$pass = 'your_pass';
$db = 'your_database';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

// Check connection mysql
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
   die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO customerphones(phone, type, notes) VALUES(?,?,?)';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $phone, $type, $note);
$index = 0;
while(COUNT($phonenums) - 1 >= $index){
   $phone = $phonenums[$index];
   $type = $type[$index];
   $note= $note[$index];
   $stmt->execute();
   $index++;
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, I think this is what I need. So I do just combine them into one array, I've thought about this, but didn't know how to actually make it work. I'm going to try this. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I have messed with this for a while, and got it to work. There are several things wrong with your answer, but it helped me to get to something that works. So, thanks :)

Comment: Failing to use `bind_param` and instead just slamming in arbitrary data with zero escaping is completely reckless. The original question is using a parameterized statement, so this is a massive regression.

Comment: The resulting array will have three positions: one with the numbers, one with the types and one with the notes. So, your `foreach` loop is incorrect. It will not return a bidimensional array(instead you're returning chars from the string), and, even if it would, you'd get an array with either all the phone numbers, all the types or all the notes. In conclusion, the inserts are incorrect. @Omgabee, since you got it to work, could you share the code with us?

Comment: Yes, I will share it. Sorry, I actually realized this and recoded something I sort of scraped together. I will edit with this code. Thanks